# Consuming web services periodically instead of frequent consumption

Tags: web-services

I have a desktop application (client) written in JavaFX which performs operations.

A user starts operation by clicking the start button, performs different entries and stops the operation.

During operation client fetches data from web services (exposed on java server).

Most of the data is updated on yearly basis on the server. 
For now, I am hitting all web services during each operation (most of the web services return same data as data changes yearly)

```
//following function is called on operation start
getMataDataFromServer() {
    List<ShiftDetail> shiftDetails = getShiftDetailsFromServer();
    List<Day> weeklyOffDays = getWeeklyOffDayMetadata();
    List<Day> holidays = getHolidayMetaData();
    //and so on like 8 different meta data of large size which slow down response time.

}
```

Is there any best solution to this problem as I don't want to hit yearly web services during each operation.

or can I perform web service caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce operation cycle time and large response time I have introduced SQLite database on a client side.

Created tables for each metadata like holidays, shift details, week off etc. along with master metadata table.

On server side written new web service to provide last updated time of metadata web services.

During each operation consuming last updated web service for checking data is changed or not after operation start.

```
fetchAndSaveMetaDataLastUpdatedInfo() {
    List<MetaData> metdataList = fetchMetaDataLastUpdatedInfo();
    // Saving meta data last updated info to local db
    saveMetaDataLastUpdatedInfoToLocalDB();
}
```

While consuming each web service checking last updated time and accordingly fetching data from local database or web service.

```
private List<ShiftDetail> fetchShiftDetails(){
    boolean fetchShiftFromDB = isMetaDataLastUpdatedAfterOperationStart(Constant.SHIFT);
        List<ShiftDetail> shiftDetails;
        if (fetchShiftFromDB) {
            shiftDetails = fetchShiftDetailsFromLocalDB();
        } else {
            shiftDetails = fetchShiftDetailsFromServer();
        }
        return shiftDetails;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with this technique?. Seems you have solved the question yourself .

Comment: I only can suggest an improvement to include an 'expiration date' to each kind of data if you know when it is going to be renewed, for example at January, 1. This would avoid the call to the service in charge of checking if data has been updated. You can also mark the last update data of each register and download only the updated data. But I can not tell if this advice is good without knowing more data from your system